# i dont understand here why put (*) in the argument what is mean?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, for-loop

hello guys I did not understand why we put * here
[y](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3sSsR.png)

```
def print_people( # here # *people # here #):
for person in people:
    print("hello" + person)
```

print_people("blabla" , "love" , "blabla")

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does \*\* (double star/asterisk) and \* (star/asterisk) do for parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-asterisk-and-star-asterisk-do-for-parameters)

Answer (score 0):

`*` In Python used to unpack data from iterables.

Example:

```
arr = [1,2,3,4,5] 

*arr will unpack the array as 1 2 3 4 5
```

Comment: thx you so much